# Retrofit Return Simple String

Tags: android, retrofit

is it possible to return only an echo string in retrofit for example in my php file i only print

```
echo "hello world";
```

i'm only new to retrofit and i haven't fully understand the retro fit.
by the way i'm curious to why i'm getting this response on may logcat

```
> 12-16 23:23:21.047  22111-22141/com.example.fragment_listview
> D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true 12-16
> 23:23:21.048  22111-22140/com.example.fragment_listview D/Retrofit﹕
> ---> HTTP GET http://192.168.0.121/news/hello 12-16 23:23:21.048  22111-22140/com.example.fragment_listview D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP
> (no body) 12-16 23:23:21.054 
> 22111-22111/com.example.fragment_listview D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
> 12-16 23:23:21.072  22111-22140/com.example.fragment_listview
> D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://192.168.0.121/news/hello 12-16
> 23:23:21.073  22111-22140/com.example.fragment_listview D/Retrofit﹕
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
> hasRequestBody(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class
> Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpMethod; or its super classes
> (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod' appears
> in /data/app/com.example.fragment_listview-1/base.apk)
>             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:321)
>             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:303)
>             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:364)
>             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:466)
>             at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
>             at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
>             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
>             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
>             at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
>             at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>             at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 12-16 23:23:21.073  22111-22140/com.example.fragment_listview D/Retrofit﹕
> ---- END ERROR
```

Comment: You can encapsulated you response in php json_encode and cast this with Callback<String>

Comment: @HugoG i already did that but still i get the same response.

Comment: You have to read the error and check your code and the documentation example. If you don't find anything, post the full code of your class where you use Retrofit

Comment: Please share code also. Although just a question
 D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://192.168.0.121/news/hello 12-16

Did you forget to put port number here?